# C# WPF Aynchronous Manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.5

I am building an application in WPF and am having trouble with manipulations blocking the UI thread. My method that handles Manipulation delta follows.

```
private void TileCanvas_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
   ManipulationDelta md = e.DeltaManipulation;
   Vector trans = md.Translation;
   Canvas.SetLeft(tileCanvas, Canvas.GetLeft(tileCanvas) + trans.X);
}
```

How can I optimise this to keep both the manipulation and the UI thread responsive? Can this be done asynchronously? (It's a slider element).

Comment: Simple answer. You cannot. Longer answer, make your method run faster.

Comment: @Aron That wasn't a long answer, just a second simple answer :D

Comment: The code appears straight-forward. Not entirely sure why it would be noticeable

Comment: that code will be very fast as it is, the reason for the slowdown is somewhere else. Did you run a profiler?

Comment: The UI thread is already very busy, rendering 400 animated elements every 50 milliseconds. Everything becomes laggy when the manipulation starts, then runs fine after it has finished. The hardware isn't the most powerful either...

Comment: I haven't run a profiler actually... I'll try that.

Comment: How are you sure this is the cause? Does disabling the above code make it go faster?

Comment: Instead of setting Canvas.Left you might set/modify the RenderTransform of the tileCanvas (e.g. use a TranslateTransform). That would at least save layout cycles.